# Jpa hibernate Formula not an entity

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a formula defines as below in one of the entity.

```
  @ElementCollection
  @Formula(
      "(select concat_ws(' ', jnt.name, jnt.locale) as da from translations jnt where 
  jnt.id=internalId)")
  private List<String> data;
```

OR

```
  @ElementCollection
  @Formula(
      "(select jnt.name, jnt.locale from translations jnt where 
  jnt.id=internalId)")
  private List<Object> data;
```

after defining any of the above formulas i am getting below exception while executing the query.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity
```

But, When try with below code in the place of above snippet. It works without any exceptions.

```
  @Formula("(select jnt.name from translations jnt where jnt.id=1)")
  private String data;
```

Can anyone help me what is wrong with the initial use of formula?

Comment: @Formula is for SQL fragments, not SQL statements, unless your mapping to an Entity.  I suspect that you're trying to pull these data from a table other than what's defined on the entity, including the entire entity class will help diagnose and understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do, but you can't use `@Formula` and `@ElementCollection` together in this way.

What you could try is: treat this as a basic-typed mapping, with a `@Formula` that evaluates to a `String`, and then write an `AttributeConverter` that parses that string to a `List`.